# How to convert a string to title case and remove duplicate spaces

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

I have a long string ("sara james  joseph  NAUMAN") which is displayed using Crystal Reports in VS2008(c#) using a stored procedure.

1. I want to convert it to title case ("Sara Williams Joseph Nauman")
2. I also want to remove spaces if there are more than two between the words.

I want to know how to do the conversion in a stored procedure, Crystal Reports formula, or .cs file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a function called ProperCase(str) that will fix the casing.

```
`ProperCase("sara james joseph NAUMAN")`
```

Borrowing a bit of Hariharan Anbazhagan's code; if you happen to have blank spaces before and after your string, use Trim(str).  No function comes to mind to remove blank spaces between words so this code will do the job.

```
stringvar str1;
stringvar str2;
numbervar counter;
numbervar leng;

str2 := Trim("   Big     Space   ");

leng := len(str2);
if leng>0 then
(
    for counter := 1 to leng do
    (
        If Not(Mid(str2, counter, 1) = " " and (Mid(str2, counter+1, 1)) = " ") Then
        (
            str1:=str1 + Mid(str2, counter, 1)
        )
    );
str1
)
```

Comment: Just a small suggestion: There is really no need to use the `Mid()` function. Strings can be referenced as character arrays, so `Mid(str2, counter, 1)` is the same as `str2[counter]`. It's a little cleaner and easier to read that way.

Comment: I want to do conversion from store procedure,

Comment: @Ryan: Good point, I keep forgetting that strings are arrays.

Comment: @hussian: If you mean a stored [function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.businessobjects.integration.eclipse.doc.crdesigner%2Freportdesigner%2Fcrconcreatingcustomfunctions.htm), you can follow craig example below.

Answer (score 1):

Custom formula `Format()`:

```
// Format()
Function (Stringvar value, Optional Stringvar delimiter:=",")

    // create an array of formetted names (and blanks)
    // "sara james joseph       NAUMAN" => "Sara James Joseph       Nauman"
    Local Stringvar Array temp:=Split( ProperCase(value), " ");

    Local Stringvar Array values;

    Local Numbervar i;

    // remove empty array positions
    For i:= 1 To Ubound(temp) Do (

      If temp[i]<>"" Then (

        Redim Preserve values[Ubound(values)+1];
        values[Ubound(values)]:=temp[i]

      )

    );

    // delimited list
    Join(values, delimiter);
```

Reference it in a formula:

```
// returns "Sara,James,Joseph,Nauman"
Format("sara james joseph       NAUMAN")
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.net, the equivalent is:

```
str1 = StrConv(str1, vbProperCase)
```

This is just an FYI in case someone else is looking for this in VB.net.